# Copy constructors in C++ and copying values into objects

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class foo {
     int number;
     char string[20];
public:
     foo( ) { 
          set(3, 5); 
     }
     void set (int a, int b) { 
          number = a + b;
        strcpy( string, "summer" ); 
     }

     foo (const foo & c ) { 
     }

     void output() { 
          cout << number << ',' << string << endl;  
     }
};

void showyanothing (foo);

int main() {
     foo a, b;
     showyanothing( a );
     a.output();
     b.output();
}

void showyanothing (foo z) { 
     cout << "... how are you?\n";
     z.output(); 
}
```

Output

```
... hello ...
... how are you?
-1218897013,l·ôl·Y·ôl·À
8,summer
8,summer
```

The line with `-1218897013,l·ôl·Y·ôl·À`, those are the values in the object Z created by the copy constructor. If I change my copy constructor to the following, outputting object z will yield `10, summer.1.2.3`. Why? Where did the values magically get inserted from into Z?

new copy constructor

```
 foo (const foo & c ) { 
     number = c.number + 2;
     strcpy( string, c.string );
     strcat( string, ".1.2.3" );
 }
```

new output:

```
... how are you?
10,summer.1.2.3
8,summer
8,summer
```

In the copy constructor, what I'm confused about is why does c.number equate to 8, and c.string equate to summer? Where did it get those values from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple check out the function call

```
void showyanothing (foo z)
```

The copy constructor is invoked here. Since you have a copy constructor in the earlier code and with no initialization of the data members, it prints random val. On the other hand, when you edit the copy constructor you get the result ( i.e. the following is invoked!)

```
foo (const foo & c ) { 
     number = c.number + 2;
     strcpy( string, c.string );
     strcat( string, ".1.2.3" );
 }
```

Hope it solves your doubt :)

Comment: I understand but isn't foo & c referencing z, in which z is empty, so c.number would be nothing? Just confused how c.number holds 8 and c.string holds summer.

Comment: If you see in the code you have both the default constructor and also the copy constructor. The default constructor is invoked when you create the object. Then when the function call is made, the copy constructor is invoked(look at the function signature). Now compare the two codes :)

Answer (score 0):

The first version of your copy constructor does not initialize foo's member variables.  Therefore `number` and `string` will contain random data--whatever happened to be in RAM at the location where the new object gets instantiated.

The second version correctly assigns values to the member variables, based on the object getting passed in by reference (the object we're supposed "copying").  In this case you are passing in `a` (because you call `showyanothing(a)`) which was instantiated using the default constructor, which gave it the number 8 and the string "summer".

Answer (score 0):

Object occupy memory whether you initialize it or not. Memory contains some arbitrary value. If you don't initialize it, it can be anything. That explains the initial garbage output you get.

Next you provide sensible copy constructor, which initializes object based on source object which is passed to it. In the beginning of your `main()` you create object `a` which is constructed using default constructor, and hence gets its `number` member set to 8 as a result of `set(3,5)` call. `showyanothing (foo z)` function gets its parameter passed by value, which means creating a new instance of class `foo` using copy constructor which receives object `a`, it adds 2 to `a`'s `number` (which is 8) and copies the `string`.